# jquery random sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, random

i'm currently working on a small jquery project. now i have one (maybe simple to solve) problem. following my code - i have shortened it and dropped a few lines (only array positions)

```
function setupblurb()
{
    var blurb = new Array(); 
    blurb[0] = "text1";
    blurb[1] = "text2";
    blurb[23] = "text24";
    return blurb;
}

function setupweblinks()
{
    var weblink = new Array(); 
    weblink[0] = "days/day1.html";
    weblink[1] = "days/day2.html";      
    weblink[23] = "days/day24.html";    
    return weblink; 
}

function setuppositions()
{
    var positions = new Array(); 
    positions[0] = "1";
    positions[1] = "2";     
    positions[23] = "24";
    return positions;
}
```

in another script i output the 'days'. it works well (sorted from 1-24) but now i want to know how i can randomly sort the output? i have the function 'setuppositions()' but when i change the positions there, e.g.:

```
positions[0] = "5";
```

it links the output to day1 instead of day5.

i am grateful for every help i get :) thank you!

Comment: It'd be easier if you had an array of objects rather than multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could define the Array variables in the global scope above the functions:

```
var blurb = new Array(); 
var weblink = new Array(); 
var positions = new Array(); 

function setupblurb()
{
...
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/kGUA2/)